# Declaring functions in a class

Tags: python, class, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [python 'self' explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/python-self-explained)

I am a beginner in Python. I was going through the tutorials on Classes and Iterators when I had a doubt that I was unable to explain to myself. The program text below was a part of a class which calculates area.

```
def __init__(self,len,wid):
    self.length=len
    self.width=wid

def calculate_area(self)
    return self.length*self.width

def print_area(self)
    print 'Area='+str(self.calculate_area())
```

What I am unable to understand is why do the function's argument list have "self"? What is its role? Why are every variable resolved with "self"?

Comment: You need two underscores for the `__init__()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is similar to this pointer in C++ (if you have come from C++ background)
Typical usage would be that the members of objects can be referenced by self in case if there is an ambiguity. e.g.

```
def calculate_area(self, length)
    return self.length*self.width
```

Above length is an argument for calculate_area function.
if the object also has length member then it can be resolved by using self.length

Refer existing answer here:

[What is the purpose of self?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/python-self-explained)

Comment: You mean the local variable inside area is resolved by self.length so that the compiler understands this is a variable local to the function?

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know I'm too new on the Python world but I think that Python does not provide the `this` value as C# or Java do, so this is the mechanism that Python use to define itself in its classes.

Anyway you can see that you don't need to pass the `self` as parameter in the function call, because Python does for you.

This is my theory, but I'm also interested to know it so If anyone can say more about this, I think we will be very thankfull.

See you!